# Pandas store column value queried by index as a list

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to store the value I printed by queried the data frame using index, I tried use .tolist and list but I cannot store them. If there any way I can store these values and make the two query results together in one data frame?

Thank you in advance!
[image]

I tried use .tolist and list but I cannot store them.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.